# Unity3D Applying Texture - Model turns black

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am following a course to learn Unity3D.

Game Development for iPhone/iPad Using Unity iPhone Tutorials

http://www.vtc.com/products/Game-Development-for-iPhone-iPad-Using-Unity-iPhone-Tutorials.htm

I am following along whatever author is doing on the screen. He is using Unity 1.6 and I am using Unity 3.40f5

When I try to apply the texture as he does in the movie, my model turns black. Is there something trivial that I am missing here?

Also find the screenshot attached.

1. Whats happening in the movie with author - [image]
2. Whats happening on my screen - [image]

Comment: did you drag the material on the object? did you add a light source?

Comment: I voted to close this question as off topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the Help Center. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell from screen grabs but your material looks correct, assuming it says "Bumped Diffuse" after shader, I can't tell.

When you first drag your model the scene, before applying a texture, it should self shade.  If it doesn't, you need to regenerate your model's normals by clicking on the model and then in the inspector look for "Normals and Tangents."  After Normals choose "Calculate" the click "Apply" at the bottom, see what happens.  I don't know your model type but Unity has given me trouble in the past with Wavefront .obj files predefining their normals.

The other possible issue is a faulty UV import.  If the tutorial is from v1.6 it is possible the model included with the tutorial isn't importing correctly.  I've had a similar issue where the UV's were all set to '0 0' so only the lowest corner pixel of my texture was used.  Unity can't do anything for you there.  You can test this by creating a new material.  Set the shader to diffuse.  Set 'Base(RGB)' texture to 'none', and set 'Main Color' to something like blue.  Apply it to your model.  If you don't define a texture then your model should appear blue.  If it does, it means you likely have a UV import problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just create the material as well but I think you did not import it to the object.